# Can't seem to launch an activity from a notification (from code in an AAR library), why?

Tags: android

I'm at the beginning of a medium sized android project and I can't seem to get a notification to launch an activity.  Depending on how I try I get different errors.

The overall layout is as follows.  There are three relevant projects: Core, Components and EntryPoint.  Core is pure jvm and doesn't depend on or conflict with Android.  Components compiles to an AAR that EntryPoint depends on to build the APK.  I trigger both of these projects from an sbt build, the relevant parts of which are:

```
import com.eny.plugin.spi.Imports.{ mapExport, SpiKeys }

lazy val androidSettings = Seq( proguardOptions in Android ++= Seq( "-keep class * extends BASE.core.Component"    // this from http://scala-on-android.taig.io/proguard/
                                                                   // TODO: once it works try taking these next two out and see if it breaks
                                                                  , "-keep class * extends BASE.android.core.AndroidComponent"
                                                                  , "-keep class BASE.android.components.** { *; }"
                                                                  ))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(core, androidEntryPoint)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)  // these settings are to keep SpiPlugin from doing every interface

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(exportJars := true)

lazy val androidComponents = (project in file("android-components"))
  .dependsOn(core)
  .enablePlugins(AndroidLib)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(androidSettings: _*)
  .settings(exportJars := true)

lazy val androidEntryPoint = (project in file("android-entry-point"))
  .dependsOn(core, androidComponents)
  .enablePlugins(AndroidApp, SpiPlugin)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(androidSettings: _*)
  .settings(resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task{
    // This task copies the list of Components to the appropriate place to ensure
    // it gets included in an accessible place in the APK
    val res = collectResources.value._1  // item _1 here is for assets, item _2 is for resources.  See the output of sbt "show androidEntryPoint/android:collectResources"
    val componentList = res / componentName
    IO.delete(componentList)
    IO.touch(componentList)
    mapExport.value.foreach { name =>
      IO.append(componentList, IO.read(target.value / name))
    }
    List(componentList)
  }.taskValue)
```

AFAICT the build isn't the problem, but it's here because it may help.

Unsurprisingly the main activity is in androidEntryPoint.  It's basically a ListView populated by reading the list of available components (generated at compile time by the SPI plugin), when the user touches a component from the list it spins up a ComponentService (which extends android.app.Service), promotes it to the foreground, and starts a thread that runs the component's main loop.  So far, all of that works perfectly.

The problem comes when a component (which is running in a thread in a foreground Service) wants to have a UI.  My thinking on how to do that was to have components that want UIs throw up a Notification which has the UI Action as it's pending intent... but so far I haven't gotten that to work.  The code is as follows:

```
def uiActivityClass: Option[Class[_ <: Activity]] = None

def addUiNotification: Unit = uiActivityClass.foreach { cls =>
  // These two lines will crash it
  val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
  stackBuilder.addParentStack(cls)
  // But if you comment out the above lines the below lines don't crash... or do anything else
  val goToUi = new Intent(context, cls)
  goToUi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
  val pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, goToUi, 0)
  val notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                     .setContentTitle(name)
                                     .setContentText("Go to the component UI")
                                     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.scala_android)
                                     .setContentIntent(pending)
                                     .build
  Option(context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)) match {
    case Some(mgr: NotificationManager) =>
      mgr.notify(instanceId.getLeastSignificantBits.toInt, notification)
    case Some(_) => log.error("This should be impossible, getSystemService returned a different type than was requested")
    case None => log.error("Couldn't get the notification service... are you running an ancient version of android?")
  }
}
```

If I run it as is the app crashes and logcat says `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{BASE.android.entrypoint/BASE.android.components.examples.createVoiceControl.VoiceControlActivity}`, which I don't quite understand, because if I use `cls.newInstance` to instantiate cls I get a completely different Android error, which means it is on the classpath.

If instead I comment out the first two lines I get a completely different problem.  The notification shows up as expected, but when I touch it the notifications pull down rolls back up, but nothing else happens, my activity never starts.  In this case, logcat tells me:

```
D  ( 1557) StatusBar: Clicked on content of 0|BASE.android.entrypoint|1427507168|null|10133
D  (  376) audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
I  (  944) ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=BASE.android.entrypoint/BASE.android.components.examples.createVoiceControl.VoiceControlActivity} from uid 10133 on display 0
D  (  376) audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
D  (  376) msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
D  (  376) audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
D  (  376) audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback speaker
W  (  944) InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@9f17259 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@3915465
D  ( 1557) PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand icons* alerts system_info* back home recent clock search quick_settings >
```

I'm sure I'm missing some finicky little Android detail, but poking around at other SO answers hasn't licked this one yet.  For the sake of completeness, here is the merged AndroidManifest.xml file I'm working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="BASE.android.entrypoint"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.0.2-SNAPSHOT" >

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="23"
      android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<activity
    android:name="BASE.android.components.examples.createVoiceControl.VoiceControlActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity="" >
</activity>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/scala_android"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service android:name="BASE.android.entrypoint.AndroidComponentService" />

    <activity
        android:name="BASE.android.entrypoint.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?  Could the crash when I use the TaskStackBuilder be related to the fact that the `VoiceControlActivity` is not within the `<application>` in the manifest?

Edit: quick update, the `ComponentInfo{BASE.android.entrypoint/BASE.android.components.examples.createVoiceControl.VoiceControlActivity}` thing was bugging me, because the activity was not in the BASE.android.entrypoint package (as specified by the AndroidManifest file in the Components project) so I tried with a manually constructed ComponentName with the correct package, it gave me the same issues (albeit with the different package reflected in the illegal argument exception).

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

The problem was in the way I wrote the manifest on the library side.  My logic was "this isn't an application, so clearly it doesn't need an `<application>`, surely the manifest merge operation won't insert the activity into the wrong part of the manifest, that would be silly!"

So, yeah.  It turns out the manifest merge isn't that smart, and you have to have a `<application>` tag to contain your activities and whatnot (even in a project destined to become an AAR).  The correct merged AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="BASE.android.entrypoint"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0.2-SNAPSHOT" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/scala_android"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service android:name="BASE.android.entrypoint.AndroidComponentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="BASE.android.entrypoint.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="BASE.android.components.examples.createVoiceControl.VoiceControlActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity="" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```